# Coloured compounds on reacting with oxygen

Tags: inorganic-chemistry

In the reaction of chlorine gas with water, Hydrogen chloride and nascent oxygen is produced.The reaction of any coloured substance with this nascent oxygen makes it colourless.

Is it true?if yes, how?

Answer (score 1):

The feature that makes colored compounds colored is the one that makes the compounds easily oxidized. When the compound is oxidized, something does not exist anymore. I'm not giving you a straight answer since you will experience a nice enlightenment when you figure that out. Take a look at the structure of beta-carotene, for example. Where would the oxygen go and what would the structure look like after that?